# porque no funcionan lo botones del menu?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un menú creado pero por alguna razón no me detecta los botones del menú.
La app funciona pero cuando le doy al menú no hace nada de lo que le he puesto.
Este es mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText et1, et2, et3, et4, et5;
    private TextView tv1;
    private Context contexto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        contexto = this;
        et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3 = findViewById(R.id.et3);
        et4 = findViewById(R.id.et4);
        et5 = findViewById(R.id.et5);
    }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
         return true;
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String message = "El alumno: " + et1.getText() + " " + et2.getText() + "\n vive: "
                + et3.getText() + "\n telefono: " + et4.getText() + "\n se matriculo " + et5.getText();
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.boton1:
                Snackbar.make(tv1, "" + message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.boton2:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contexto);
                builder.setTitle("Información");
                builder.setMessage(message);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                return true;
            case R.id.boton3:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(contexto);
                builder2.setMessage("¿Confirma Salir?")
                        .setTitle("Confirmacion para salir de la aplicacion")
                        .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Toast.makeText(contexto,"adios",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                dialog.cancel();
                                }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                 builder2.create();
                 return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando el método `onContextItemSelected()`, esto es incorrecto, debes usar el método [**onOptionsItemSelected()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=es-419#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        return true;
    }
```

---

> [**onOptionsItemSelected()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=es-419#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) : método que es llamado cuando el
>   usuario selecciona un elemento del menú de opciones (incluidos los
>   elementos de acción de la barra de app).